# Segmentation Fault when accessing private class variable

Tags: c++, qt

The problem I'm having has been discussed multiple times, but I still don't understand how to fix the issue I'm having. I used to program in C++ a lot but switched over to Java for a while due to work. I'm getting back into C++ and I'm now having a lot of issues with memory management/pointers/references etc. This problem stems from that.

For context, these are files for a Qt 5.14 project that I'm working on.

The problem is that I have a private class variable named `loggerLevel` and the method that creates the segmentation fault error is `getLevel` which just returns the value of the loggerLevel. The that is *supposed* to be stored in the variable is an enum named Level that is defined in the header of the class.

I don't know if the problem stems from my lack of knowledge or if I am misunderstanding something about how classes work in C++, or if its something completely different. In any case, if anyone can help me out that would be great :)

--- Source code below ---

logger.cpp

```cpp
#include "logger.h"

QString debugHTML = "<font color=\"gray\">";
QString infoHTML = "<font color=\"black\">";
QString warningHTML = "<font color=\"yellow\">";
QString errorHTML = "<font color=\"orange\">";
QString criticalHTML = "<font color=\"red\">";
QString endHTML = "</font><br>";

Logger::Logger(QObject *parent,
               QString fileName,
               QTextEdit *editor) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_editor = editor;
    m_showDate = true;
    loggerLevel = Level::INFO;
    if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
        file = new QFile;
        file->setFileName(fileName);
        file->open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text);
    }
}

void Logger::write(const QString &value) {

    QString text = value;

    if (m_showDate) {
        text = QDateTime::currentDateTime()
                /*.toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss ") + text;*/
                .toString("hh:mm:ss:  ") + text;
    }

    QTextStream out(file);
    out.setCodec("UTF-8");

    if (file != 0) {
        out << text;
    } else {
        //TODO: add QMessageBox here with error
    }

    //Adds HTML color/formatting
    switch(loggerLevel)
    {
        case DEBUG: text = debugHTML + text; break;
        case INFO: text = infoHTML + text; break;
        case WARNING: text = warningHTML + text; break;
        case ERROR: text = errorHTML + text; break;
        case CRITICAL: text = criticalHTML + text; break;
        default: text = infoHTML + text; break;
    }
    text = text + endHTML;

    if (m_editor != 0) {
        m_editor->insertHtml(text);
    } else {
        //TODO: add QMessageBox here with error
    }
}

void Logger::write(const Level &level, const QString &value) {
    Level prevLoggerLevel = Logger::getLevel();
    Logger::setLevel(level);
    write(value);
    Logger::setLevel(prevLoggerLevel);
}

//--------Setters--------
void Logger::setLevel(const Level &level) {
    loggerLevel = level;
}

void Logger::setShowDateTime(bool value) {
    m_showDate = value;
}


//--------Getters--------
Logger::Level Logger::getLevel() {
    return loggerLevel;
}


Logger::~Logger() {
    if (file != 0) {
        file->close();
    }
}
```

logger.h

```cpp
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDateTime>

class Logger : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Logger(QObject *parent,
                    QString fileName = 0,
                    QTextEdit *editor = 0);
    ~Logger();
    void setShowDateTime(bool value);
    enum Level
    {
        DEBUG,
        INFO,
        WARNING,
        ERROR,
        CRITICAL
    };

private:
    QFile *file;
    QTextEdit *m_editor;
    bool m_showDate;
    Level loggerLevel;


signals:

public slots:
    void write(const QString &value);
    void write(const Level &level, const QString &value);
    void setLevel(const Level &level);
    Level getLevel();

};

#endif // LOGGER_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```cpp
#include <string>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "settingsdialog.h"
#include "logger.h"

Logger *logger;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString logFileName = "log.txt";
    Logger *logger = new Logger(this, logFileName, ui->loggerOutput);
    logger->write(Logger::Level::INFO, "Logger Initilized!");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked()
{

    SettingsDialog settingsDialog;
    settingsDialog.setModal(true);
    settingsDialog.exec();
}


//Left Side of controller
void MainWindow::on_s_leftJoystickX_Throttle_sliderMoved(int position)
{ ui->l_leftJoystickX->setText(QStringLiteral("X-Axis: %1%").arg(position)); }

void MainWindow::on_s_leftJoystickY_Throttle_sliderMoved(int position)
{ ui->l_leftJoystickY->setText(QStringLiteral("Y-Axis: %1%").arg(position)); }

void MainWindow::on_s_leftTrigger_Throttle_sliderMoved(int position)
{ ui->l_leftTrigger->setText(QStringLiteral("Trigger: %1%").arg(position)); }

void MainWindow::on_s_joystickThrottle_sliderMoved(int position)
{ ui->l_joystickThrottle->setText(QStringLiteral("Throttle: %1%").arg(position)); }


//Right Side of controller
void MainWindow::on_s_rightJoystickX_Throttle_sliderMoved(int position)
{ ui->l_rightJoystickX->setText(QStringLiteral("X-Axis: %1%").arg(position)); }

void MainWindow::on_s_rightJoystickY_Throttle_sliderMoved(int position)
{ ui->l_rightJoystickY->setText(QStringLiteral("Y-Axis: %1%").arg(position)); }

void MainWindow::on_s_rightTrigger_Throttle_sliderMoved(int position)
{ ui->l_rightTrigger->setText(QStringLiteral("Trigger: %1%").arg(position)); }

void MainWindow::on_s_keyboardThrottle_sliderMoved(int position)
{ ui->l_keyboardThrottle->setText(QStringLiteral("Throttle: %1%").arg(position)); }

void MainWindow::on_b_keyboardAction_1_clicked()
{
    logger->write(Logger::Level::CRITICAL, "test");
}
```

There are more files, but I believe they are not relevant to the problem, if needed I can post the other files aswell.

**-----Solution!-----**

@churill Solution explains what needs to be done to fix this problem but I also will detail it below to complete this question.

Since I had already made a forward declaration of logger

```cpp
Logger *logger
```

at the top of MainWindow.cpp, creating a new Logger object

```cpp
Logger *logger = new Logger(this, logFileName, ui->loggerOutput);
```

is unnecessary so calling the forward declarations variable name instead of creating a new Logger object

```cpp
logger = new Logger(this, logFileName, ui->loggerOutput);
```

fixes the problem!

Comment: I assume you have caught the crash in a debugger (that's why you know it crashes in `getLevel`)? Then if you check the call-stack, what does it look like? And what is the value of `this`?

Comment: Do you *need* to use `new`?  Try designing and coding without using dynamic memory.  See `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From first glance:

```
Logger *logger = new Logger(this, logFileName, ui->loggerOutput);
```

creates an object that has nothing to do with the global variable `logger` which is never initialized. Maybe you meant to write only

```
logger = new Logger(this, logFileName, ui->loggerOutput);
```

to initialize this global variable.

---

To somewhat address the title of your question: Yes you actually *can* call functions on invalid pointers, but then the `this`-pointer is not valid, thus accessing a member variable causes the seg-fault.

Comment: This fixed the problem! I forgot that I had already made a forward declaration of the logger so creating a new object of Logger was unnecessary. Thank you!